# coincident parcels

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a parcel layer that in some cases has multiple stacked coincident parcels on top of each other. I'm trying to identify the parcels that are duplicated like that using Postgre 9.5.1/PostGIS 2.2.

What PostGIS functions would one use to determine this?

My first thought is to create a CTE and compare the two using ST_Equals, but that is returning a very large result.

There are about 2.6 million parcels in the DB.

Here's kind of what I was thinking:

```
with first as (select gid, geom from testing.parcel_selection)

select st_equals(a.geom,b.geom) from first a, 
testing.parcel_selection b;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain your query. Exact row counts on the query source and resilt will help.

Comment: Yes, of course this query returns many rows -- you have not eliminated identities or duplicates  (e.g. `WHERE b.idcol > a.idcol`)

Comment: I believe that if you do it this way, the spatial index will not be used. You would be better off just doing a straight join on ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) and as Vince has said, add b.idcol>a.idcol also, as this will halve the comparisons. It always helps to should the EXPLAIN statament too.

Comment: This may not help but to find overlapping coincident BUP (building unit parcels) in ArcGis I did polygon to point (centroid) then intersect the centroids and summary statistics... anywhere the count of parcel FID was greater than 1 indicated a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see how this question can be off-topic after providing code in the first edit. It's clearly not general programming as spatial relationship is key.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just to `group by` the `geom` column

Comment: You may have to test for false positives, since I think that may be a simple envelope test.